# Aggregate multiple internet connections

Tags: networking, wifi

I live in a village where we have a weak Internet connection. We subscribe to 2 internet offers, in order to divide the use of the family. Sometimes we even use 3G of our phones.

My goal would be to buy a Raspberry Pi, and create only one wifi would spread the use of the internet connection equally among all internet connection available. Ideally, I can provide an interface to control the internet connections (and for example add/edit/remove 3G connections), and view usage statistics for each connection.

My problem is that I have never bought Raspberry Pi, and I'm not necessarily good at networking. My first interrogation is the number of network cards. If I take a Raspberry Pi 3, for example, there is a wifi module embedded, but is it possible to use it to serve as a hotspot, and use it at the same time to connect to multiple Internet connections wifi? Then I have no real idea how to do this aggregation system of several internet connections. I saw some tools, like [Overthebox](https://github.com/ovh/overthebox-feeds), Zeroshell or [Multipath TCP](http://multipath-tcp.org/), but I do not really have the knowledge to know if what I want to do is possible or not.

Do some of you could advise me on what I should do, or if some have already done this kind of system please?

Regards.

Comment: Aurelien, your question is very broad, which makes it off topic here. We can help with specific portions of a project, but the site format doesn't deal with such open ended inquiries.

Comment: On a different note, this is a very complex setup, and I doubt you'll find an out of the box solution for your problem. *I'm not necessarily good at networking* will probably be a significant issue in this endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

> Do some of you could advise me on what I should do

## Not this.

No version of Pi has sufficient I/O capabilities to provide this no matter what you attach to it.

> I'm not necessarily good at networking

My favorite analogies to computer technology are auto mechanics and surgery.  I am sure there are many surgeries that are much simpler, require less skill, time, and resources, than many engine repairs, and vice versa.

What you are talking about doing it not something you are very likely to set up and have working one weekend.  That's not to say given the right luck and instructions it would be impossible, just that it would most likely lead to a lot frustration.

There are no doubt true stories of non-medical people *taking out their own appendix* in the field following the right guide lines.  I know a nurse that did it once simply having seen it done enough times.  **But** for every story like this, there could be hundreds that ended in fatalities.

Make sense?  Something broke on your car and you don't have the money to pay someone to fix it.  Maybe you buy some tools and a manual and it is finished in a few hours >_>  Or maybe your car is up on blocks for the next three weeks.

So you should think very hard about what problem you are trying to solve and whether it is really solvable in the way you think.  And a raspberry pi is very unlikely to play the central role in it.